# In a function-backed Action, is it possible to autofill fields with default values based on a user-selected object?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have a function-backed Action that provides an Object selector as its first input. When the user selects an Object from the dropdown, is there a way to use the selected Object's properties to fill fields in the current Action while filling the form? In other words, to use them as default values?

For example, say I have an Action to create an Object representing a product purchase, and the first input is a dropdown to select an Object representing a customer. Can I set it up, either in the Action itself or in the function, so that selecting a customer immediately fills the Customer ID and Customer Name fields?

I know in the function I can do something like `purchase.customerId = customer.id`, but that only comes into play *after* the user submits the form. I want the user to see the auto-populated customer id in the relevant input box and be able to override it if they want.

I feel like this would be covered in the documentation, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the Action's Form, you can set default values for various form fields. You can use either static values or properties of the selected object, if there is one. See the [screenshot here in the docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/parameters-default-value/index.html#static-default-value) and look right above the "A320" near the bottom of the screenshot to see where you would select an object property value.

Additionally, when configuring an Action in a Workshop app, you can override the default values or set default values for that particular configuration of the Action. Scroll down in [these docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/actions-use/index.html#configuring-an-action-in-a-button-group) until you reach the paragraph about parameter defaults.